# PHP store PNG image in variable form URL or POST variable

Tags: php, url, post

I need to get two images coming either from `POST` or getting using image URLs and then store in a variable.
I'm using `POST` way but the `imagesx()` function says that it is not an image type.

```
$image=$_FILES["file"];

$w = imagesx($image);
$h = imagesy($image);
```

Please tell me if any other way to get image and then store in variable.

Comment: That's not how `imagesx()` and `imagesy()` work, they require a GD image resource. You want `getimagesize()`

Answer (score 2):

`imagesx` and `imagesy` accept an image resource. What you're giving it is an array.

You might be better off looking at [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/getimagesize), as this accepts a filename (which you have, given to you in `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`) and returns useful information.